# Why does Google Search load and then reload when I search from Chrome's URL bar?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

When I search something from Google Chrome's URL bar/search bar (as I press enter), the search results appear. Then, about half a second or so later, the search results reload. It's very irritating and I don't know why it's happening.

How can one fix this issue?

Comment: I had the same problem recently. Try to disabled all extensions and then enable one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome will try and instant search along the way while you are typing

```
chrome://settings
```

look under "search" to turn this off